# Java EE Running Two JVM

Tags: java, multithreading, jakarta-ee, server

I am constructing a java EE application that runs a multitude of threads that manipulate data. I want to run these threads on a separate JVM/ services server with its own JVMs running (In order to make the application scale better). Then communicate with the threads using Java RMI.

My Question is: How Do i accomplish this? I can't find any documentation on the subject. I am currently using a Tomcat instance. Should I attempt to accomplish this with Google's app engine? If so how?

Comment: maybe using Waratek to provide a Multi-tenanted JVM provider

Comment: Also by changing the `catalina.base` variable you can set up multiple versions of tomcat on the same machine each using separate JVMS

Comment: @ScaryWombat could you send me a link to some documentation on the subjects? Im unfamiliar with them.

Comment: Can use google eh?  See http://crunchify.com/how-to-run-multiple-tomcat-instances-on-one-server/

Comment: @ScaryWombat I have read that. What I don't understand how to get them to communicate with each other using Java RMI

Comment: why use rmi?  Why not servlet technology or some other webservice?

Comment: @ScaryWombat because I have all the working code for the application written in java. I just now have to make it scalable. Running the threads on a different JVM on another tomcat instance seemed like a solution. If only I can get information from the other JVM thats running my threads.

Comment: The feature you are looking for is probably *clustering* (maybe *load balancing*). https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/cluster-howto.html Do not try to implement it on your own, use your container's features. It might be advisable to switch to an enterprise application server (like GlassFish).